# phpMyAdmin can not see Unicode value in MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I have a Unicode word table in MySQL. This is how I see it. However, when I fetch data I can see the word correctly. 
How can I change the phpMyAdmin configurations to see actual Unicode view?

[image]

Comment: have you checked if table and/or column are utf8mb4 or whatever you use.

Comment: That's "Mojibake".  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored